# Custom keyboard is automatically removed from setting

Tags: ios, swift, custom-keyboard

My custom keyboard is working properly, but it is sometimes automatically removed from settings. How can I keep a permanent custom keyboard in the device settings?

Comment: have you got any solution?

Comment: No, until i don't get any solution.

Comment: have you got the solution then please tell me..because i have same problem.Thanks

Comment: Milan until i don't get this solution.

Comment: i have same problem but not getting any solution. You got any solution ?

Comment: Sorry, until i don't get this solution.

Comment: Have you upload your keyboard to iTunes ?

Comment: yes, i already uploaded.

Comment: @Rock , did you found the solution ?